# Transferring control and data from one taskflow to another based on radio button selection

Tags: oracle-adf, webcenter, adf-task-flow

I have a specific requirement in my project that goes like this:
 There is one main page fragment which have an input field, a radio button select to perform 4 functions and a submit button. The 4 functions are 4 separate task flows in themselves. On providing the input, selection of a radio and clicking of submit button, The input must be sent to next task flow based on the radio.

I can access the data from a request param map. But I am not able to move to a separate task flow on the separate page. This is somewhat like Inter portlet communication but I am not sure.

I am having a hidden param that stores a next page that needs to be opened based on radio selection.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 0):

Besides several hacks there is one recommended approach - [Contextual Events](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16182/contextual_events.htm)
Using this events your portlets/pages can communicate with each other.
More reading at [Amis blog](http://technology.amis.nl/2013/03/14/adf-re-introducing-contextual-events-in-several-simple-steps/) or [here](http://antonis-antoniou.blogspot.ru/2011/11/adf-contextual-events.html).